# Making the For loop append, Prompt user to enter values into a list

Tags: python, for-loop, append

```
def apend():
    mylist[]
    for i in range(8):
        mylist.append(input("Enter your value:"))
        print (mylist)

append()
```

I keep getting an error; as a result, the program doesn't run. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: you will never be able to append an iteratiom of int like you did. simply follow my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you didn't put the `=` symbol to define your list.
In addition, the function name has a typo, it should have been `append` - the same way as it's being called.

Your code should look like this.

```
def append():
    mylist = []
    for i in range(8):
        mylist.append(input('Enter your value:'))
        print(mylist)

append()
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in one line only. 0 == start, 8 == the given number - 1, you can finish the iteration at the given number by doing so n+1  like explained in the second line and 1 is  the step which is + 1

```
print(list(range(0, 8, 1))) #stops iteration at 7

print(list(range(0, 8+1, 1))) #finish the iteration at the given number which is 8
```

output

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```